# Wordpress Ajax URL for function in functions.php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a desktop app and I use **$.getJSON** to get data from my wordpress site using the plugin the **WP REST API**.   This works fine and so I assume I can also make an Ajax call to a function in the functions.php?  How do I do this?  None of the examples I have seen supply the ajaxURL.  How do I find out what this is?

I have the following code:

**Functions.php (in wordpress site on server)**

```
//Called by Ajax from App - list the contents of the folder so they can be downloaded and stored locally
function folder_contents() {

    $folderPath = $_POST['path'] ;
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
    print_r($files);
    return $files;

    die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'folder_contents');
```

**app.js (run using node webkit locally from machine)**

```
//ajax call 
var data = {
    action: 'path',
    path: datafolder;
};
var ajaxurl = baseurl + '';  //WHAT IS THIS?!?!
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    console.log(response);
});
```

**-------------------EDIT----------------------**

After the answer below I have tried the below code based on the advice but I get

> "index.html:324 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_params is not defined"

**Functions.php**

```
//add code to use ajax
function add_ajax_script() {

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-js', 'ajax_params', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}

//Called by Ajax from App - list the contents of the folder so they can be downloaded and stored locally

function folder_contents() {

    $folderPath = $_POST['path'] ;
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
    wp_send_json($files);

    die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_folder_contents', 'folder_contents');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_folder_contents', 'folder_contents');


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_script' );
```

**App.js**

```
//ajax call 
        var data = {action: 'powerpoint_folder_contents',path: datafolder};
        var ajaxurl =  ajax_params.ajax_url;
        console.log(ajaxurl);
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            console.log(response);
        });
```

If I remove the **add_ajax_script()** function and simply use the below it returns 0.

> var ajaxurl =  baseurl + 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

Please help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//ajax call 
var data = {
    action: 'folder_contents',
    path: datafolder
};
var ajaxurl = baseurl + '';  //WHAT IS THIS?!?!
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    console.log(response);
});
```

And your PHP in functions.php

```
//Called by Ajax from App - list the contents of the folder so they can be downloaded and stored locally
function folder_contents() {

$folderPath = $_POST['path'] ;
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
print_r($files);
return $files;

die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_folder_contents', 'folder_contents');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_folder_contents', 'folder_contents');
```

The above add your function as an ajax action. You then call the function name in your AJAX.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: Sorry, in your JS you also need to add the ajaxurl for your site. The way i do this is by defining it and localizing the script for access. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Also see here for an example of the ajaxurl and localizing that. https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/wp/wp-localize-script-wordpress

Comment: OK, Im struggling to get this working.  I have edited my original query above to show what I have tried based on your answer

Comment: Instead of "return $files", do "echo $files".

Comment: OR, do wp_send_json($files); https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json

Comment: Ok I have changed to wp_send_json($files); and still get 0 unfortunately

Comment: Try: `function folder_contents() {

echo 'hello';

die(); 
}`

Do you see the word hello come out in the console.log?

Comment: Ive tried that and get 0, tred removing everything from that function and still get 0.  If I go directly to the file with  http://myweb.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=folder_contents I still get 0.

Comment: thansk for your help by the way, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46636/discussion-between-steve-north-and-leetee).

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see you localize the 'ajax-js' script, but is the script itself enqueued? I had to use wp_localize scripts a few weeks ago and I had to enqueue my JS script inside the function that called wp_localize script. For example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_js_script' );

function google_js_script()
{
  // Enqueue the js script     
  wp_enqueue_script('google-js', GOOGLE_PLG_URL . 'assets/js/google-places.js', array('jquery'), true);

  // Localize the enqueued JS script
  wp_localize_script( 'google-js', 'ajax_object',
    array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'place' => '' ) );
}
```

Hope this helps to debug the issue.

Comment: The JS is not used on the site itself. He is using the JS inside a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

The [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) states that you can use the global variable `ajaxurl` without declaring it first. In other words, comment out this line:

`var ajaxurl =  ajax_params.ajax_url;`

...and see if that works.

Comment: If you read that notice in its entirety you also see this: "**This is true on the administration side only.** If you are using AJAX on the front-end, you need to make your JavaScript aware of the admin-ajax.php url. A best practice is documented in the fourth example, below using `wp_localize_script()`."